# Calculating the scale factor for "bar rectangles" of Chart app

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I have an array of integer values

```
String[] values={3100,7500,8000,4200,88000,71000,32000};
```

that need to be scaled into a known height of my `JComponent` , the question is how to scale these values into e.g. h=600px?

Here is a pic just for more clarification of what i want to achieve:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bar_height = chart_height*(value/max_value)
```

To determine `bar_height`, you scale (multiply) `chart_height` by `(value/max_value)`, where:

- `bar_height` is the height of the a bar in pixels.
- `value` is the value to be charted.
- `max_value` is the maximum value on the y-axis.
- `chart_height` is the height of the chart in pixels (600 in your example).

For example:

```
88000/88000 = 1.0, or 100% of the chart height        (600px)
    0/88000 = 0, or 0% of the chart's height          (  0px)
 3100/88000 = ~0.035, or ~3.53% of the chart's height (~21px)
```

Comment: Thanks, But could you please explain to me how did you come up with this formula? does Scale factor has to do with it?