# Scaling diagrams in Java to fit one print page

Tags: java, printing, scaling, graphics2d

I have a diagramming tool that uses Java and Graphics2D.  I would like to scale the resulting diagram so it fits exactly into an 8.5 x 11 page (landscape) when printing.

I saw somewhere that page scaling is in 72ths of an inch, but I'm not sure how this relates to screen's dpi.  To make things more complex, my screen is working at 144dpi, but most users of the package will be using 72dpi or 96dpi (not sure which...?).  Has anyone experience at managing all these dpi's, including printing?

Using the java.awt.print package I can print my diagram, but they are too big, using several pages. I can scale them using `Graphics.scale(double, double)`, but how do I calculate the scaling factor so the diagrams fit on one page? And is `Graphics.scale(double, double)` the right tool anyway?

Comment: On a screen, normally one unit is one screen pixel. On the printer, it might be one pt (= 1/72 inch).

Comment: What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: Hi Paŭlo - the diagramming tool creates nice diagrams that fit on my screen.  However, when I print them using awt.print, it uses more than one page, and I don't want users to have to stick pages together using sticky tape!  So I would like to scale the diagrams to fit in one page. The scale function seems to work, but I don't know how to calculate the scaling factor.  Also, I'm not sure scale(double, double) is the appropriate function - is there one that is more appropriate for this job, e.g. a print attribute?  TIA

Comment: I added the actual question to your question. I myself don't have any experience of printing with Java, though.

Comment: Thanks, Paŭlo - that's great! Hopefully there is someone out there who can point me in the right direction :-)

Comment: Experimentally I tried a scaling factor of .67, and the result looks good - but what does this number come from?  E.g. is it the ratio between 96 and 144?  I mean it is mathematically - but I want to be able to calculate it for different environments...

Comment: So, maybe Java calculated with a screen dpi of 96, wile it really is 144?

Comment: I think the formula included in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602644/calculating-the-scale-factor-for-bar-rectangles-of-chart-app/5602658#5602658) can helps you, but I don't sure.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code around the web. I think it fixes your problem.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 
//Scale the component to fit    
//Calculate the scale factor to fit the window to the page.
double scaleX = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
double scaleY = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();
double scale = Math.min(scaleX,scaleY);  //Get minimum scale factor
```

I hope it helps you. [Link to the web](http://www.dlib.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/viewvc/viewvc.cgi/dml-open/standalone-timeliner/trunk/src/edu/indiana/dml/ui/timeliner/PrintUtilities.java?pathrev=753&view=diff&r1=753&r2=129&diff_format=s)

Regards!

Comment: This calculates the size the component should have, not a scale factor.

Comment: The `pageFormat.getImageableWidth()` function returns the width, in 1/72nds of an inch and the same to `pageFormat.getImageableHeight()`function with the height. ([Link to PageFormat JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/PageFormat.html)). Then, they return the scale. Moreover, the last line of the code selects the minimum scale factor in order to select the best of them.

Comment: They return the absolute size, which is a quite different thing than a scale factor (which would be a ratio between two sizes).

Comment: Ok. I read it again and now understand that "1/72nds of an inch" is the metric unit. Sorry, I mixed up the explanation due to my level of English. =S

Comment: I wanted to split the bounty between the two responders, as you both helped steer me on the right path - TheCharliemops more so!  Although I don't think his/her answer was complete, the Marty Hall page has some good stuff there - and I was able to do a search on it pageFormat.getImageableWidth, which led me to a page by JM Soan. which has even more good stuff in it: http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_print_in_Java !   So thanks, guys - I think I'm on track now!

Comment: I accessed the link you sent and I just understand completely the solution. The scale factor is calculated whit this formula `scale = pageFormat.getImageableWidth()/
     printPane.getMinimumSize().getWidth()` and applied using the function `graphics2D.scale(scale,scale)`(according with JM Soan wiki) Thanks for the bounty but I'm conscious of Paŭlo deserves it as well